# Is SO a good place to ask about hardware/firmware mouse issues?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've got a sticky mouse (not physically sticky) and am wondering if I asked on SO would it likely get flagged?  If so, where would be a better place to ask?

I think it might have to do with firmware or even malfunctioning hardware but I am just not sure.  Do I post on SO under the pretense that it's an issue with my mouse drivers?

Comment: Even if it *was* an issue with your mouse drivers, that would still be off-topic for SO unless your question was about your attempt to re-program your mouse drivers. Updating/repairing software is not the same as writing it.

Comment: Why bother?  Take the mouse and throw it in the gd trash basket.  Buy a new mouse for 1$ off fleabay.

Comment: Reasonable, except its a built-in laptop mouse.

Comment: If you downvote me, please tell me why so I make sure not to do it again in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow is meant for software development problems, not physical hardware problems.  The only site that would fit would be [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).